# Enumerate available SignalR Server hub methods on the client side

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using SignalR.Client library on c# to connect to a SignalR hub. I don't have a documentation for the code on the server side, therefore I don't have a list of all available methods that I can call from the server using Hub.Invoke.
Is there a way that I can enumerate on all the available methods on the server side?

Comment: You are getting an html document and need to use a html parser.

Comment: I don't understand what html document you are talking about. @jdweng

Comment: The html is in the response.

Comment: No, there is no built in way to do this.